# Not displaying blockquote and background in html

Tags: html, css, blockquote

I am trying to create a snippit of HTML which looks like this:

[image]

I've written some code, but the background, italics, and left side quotes are not displaying correctly. Here's what I've tried:

```css
mission blockquote.style1 {
    font: 14px/20px italic;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-top: 1px solid #e1cc89;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1cc89;
    margin: 5px;
    background-image: url(../images/openquote1.gif);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 23px;
}

.mission blockquote.style1 span {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(images/openquote1.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class=""mission>
    <h2>Mission</h2>
    <hr>
    <blockquote>
        <p class="style1">
            <span>Our mission is to grow with our customers by providing quality products,timely delievery & personalised services</span>
        </p>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has rules and standards, when you don't follow them you can't expect "magic" to happen.

You didn't:

1. follow proper selector rules (`mission blockquote.style1` is not the same as `.mission blockquote .style1`)
2. follow proper `font` property rules (must have font-family, must be in correct order)
3. use proper html structure (`class=""mission` is just wrong)

On top of that:

1. if you expect quote signs, you need to put them in the HTML
2. if you set a full solid black background, you're not going to see anything

Long story short: Take your time to write proper code.

```css
.mission blockquote .style1 {
  font: italic 14px/20px serif;
  padding: 8px;
/*      background-color: #000000;*/
  border-top: 1px solid #e1cc89;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1cc89;
  margin: 5px;
/*      background-image: url(../images/openquote1.gif);*/
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 23px;
  }
.mission blockquote .style1 span {
     display: block;
/*         background-image: url(images/openquote1.gif);*/
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: bottom right;
   }
```

```html
<div class="mission">
<h2>Mission</h2>
<hr>
<blockquote><p class="style1"><span>Our mission is to grow with our customers by providing quality products,timely delievery & personalised services</span></p></blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now don't used to this

```
.mission blockquote.style1 span
```

according your html used to this

```
.mission blockquote .style1 span
```

`.class-1.class-2` **means** `<div class="class-1 class-2"></div>`

`.class-1 .class-2` **means** `<div class="class-1"> <div  class=".class2"></div>`

## ==============================================

```css
.mission blockquote .style1 {
  font: 14px/20px italic;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #e1cc89;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1cc89;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image: url(../images/openquote1.gif);
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 23px;
  }
.mission blockquote.style1 span {
     display: block;
     background-image: url(images/openquote1.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: bottom right;
   }
```

```html
<div class="mission">
<h2>Mission</h2>
<hr>
<blockquote><p class="style1"><span>Our mission is to grow with our customers by providing quality products,timely delievery & personalised services</span></p></blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add proper space for css rule.

```css
.mission blockquote .style1 {
  font: 14px/20px italic;
  padding: 8px;
//  background-color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px solid #e1cc89;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1cc89;
  margin: 5px;
  background-image: url(../images/openquote1.gif);
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 23px;
  }
.mission blockquote .style1 span {
     display: block;
     background-image: url(images/openquote1.gif);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: bottom right;
   }
```

```html
<div class="mission">
<h2>Mission</h2>
<hr>
<blockquote><p class="style1"><span>Our mission is to grow with our customers by providing quality products,timely delievery & personalised services</span></p></blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give space between `.mission blockquote.style1` if you are not using `.style1` class in `blockquote` tag like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ut3b453d/)**

```
.mission blockquote .style1 {..}
.mission blockquote .style1 span {..}
```

otherwise change your HTML structure like this:

```
 <blockquote class="style1">        
    <span>Our mission is to grow with our customers by providing quality products,timely delievery & personalised services</span>      
    </blockquote>
```